# Binary search a sorted list of integers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

`y` is the value I am searching for. Is this the correct implementation for binary search?

```
y= 3
x= range(0,100)
left = 0
right = len(x)-1
mid=int((left+right)/2)

while x[mid]!=y:
    if x[mid]>y:
        right = mid
        mid=int((left+right)/2)
    if x[mid]<y:
        left = mid
        mid=int((left+right)/2)
```

Comment: If you're using this code elsewhere and not implementing for the exercise, you should use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html), which has functions which do this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PEP-8

[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a style guide for Python.
It contains several practices which you should follow, like having spaces around operators.  Use a tool, like pylint, to ensure you follow these practices.

### Integer Division

```
mid=int((left+right)/2)
```

Python comes with a built-in integer division operator: `//`.  You should use it.

```
mid = (left + right) // 2
```

### Termination

```
while x[mid] != y:
```

You are searching until you find the desired value.  What if the desired value is not present?  You will search forever???  Consider adding a different stopping condition.

### Redundancy

```
    if x[mid]>y:
        #...
        mid=int((left+right)/2)
    if x[mid]<y:
        #...
        mid=int((left+right)/2)
```

Since you are looping while `x[mid] != y`, your only real choices are for `x[mid] > y` or `x[mid] < y`.  Instead of testing the second condition, how about using `else:`?

Since you enter will either the `x[mid] > y` then clause, or the `x[mid] < y` then clause, you will always be executing `mid=int((left+right)/2)`.  You can safely move those two statements out if the `if`, and unconditionally execute it at the end.  As in:

```
    if x[mid] > y:
        #...
    else:
        #...
    mid = (left + right) // 2
```

### Efficiency

If you start with `left=0, right=99, mid=49`, and find `x[mid]>y` is true, you proceed to search in the range `left=0, right=49`.  But you've already tested `x[49]` and found the value wasn't there; you don't need to include it in your search range anymore.  Similarly, when you find `x[mid]<y`, you don't need to include that `mid` point as the `left` end of your range.

```
    if x[mid] > y:
        right = mid - 1
    else:
        left = mid + 1
```

### Bug

Your existing algorithm will not terminate for certain numbers.  If you search for `99`, the value of `mid` will take on the following values:

```
49, 74, 86, 92, 95, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, ...
```